# Custom NSWindow with rounded corners which clip subviews

Tags: cocoa, calayer, nswindow

I'm trying to create a custom `NSWindow`, so I've created one with the proper borderless window mask and that works. I provide my own content view which is fine. But what I'm trying to do is draw with rounded corners that **also** clip subviews to those corners. Is this possible?

In my content view, I can override `drawRect:` and draw a path with round corners, but when I add subviews to this, they aren't clipped.

I can instead make my content view layer-backed and give it a corner radius (with `masksToBounds` set to `YES`) but when I add subviews, they're still not clipped by my round corners.

Is there a way to do this? Or some way to draw an NSWindow without a title bar and which I'd have full control over the drawing, and yet maintain the rounded, clipping corners?

Answer (score 13):

What I was able to do is provide a custom subclass of my NSWindow:

```
@implementation ELGRoundWindow

- (id)initWithContentRect:(NSRect)contentRect styleMask:(NSUInteger)aStyle backing:(NSBackingStoreType)bufferingType defer:(BOOL)flag
{
    self = [super initWithContentRect:contentRect styleMask:NSBorderlessWindowMask backing:bufferingType defer:flag];

    if ( self )
    {
        [self setStyleMask:NSBorderlessWindowMask];
        [self setOpaque:NO];
        [self setBackgroundColor:[NSColor clearColor]];
    }

    return self;
}


- (void) setContentView:(NSView *)aView
{
    aView.wantsLayer            = YES;
    aView.layer.frame           = aView.frame;
    aView.layer.cornerRadius    = 20.0;
    aView.layer.masksToBounds   = YES;


    [super setContentView:aView];

}

@end
```

and then in IB, I changed the class of my content view to ELGRoundView:

```
@implementation ELGRoundView

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{
    [[NSColor colorWithCalibratedRed:0.0 green:0.5 blue:1 alpha:1] set];
    NSRectFill(dirtyRect);
}

@end
```

I placed another square subview in my content view with the following:

```
@implementation ELGSquareView

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{
    [[NSColor colorWithCalibratedRed:0.0 green:0 blue:1 alpha:1] set];
    NSRectFill(dirtyRect);
}

@end
```

I ended up with:

[image: Rounded window with clipped subview]

Comment: Other readers should note that OpenGL applications should only use one `glDrawArrays()` command for the entire scene, otherwise the layer causes weird results. More in the scope of this question, use a corner radius of 4.5-5.0 for OS X style corners. You can also keep the normal title bar, if you want, without it looking too different.

Comment: @ericgorr any idea how to get shadow on this?

Answer (score 5):

What @ericgorr is suggesting is correct. In addition if you want the window to be movable and resizable change the init of the NSWindow as follows,

```
- (id)initWithContentRect:(NSRect)contentRect
                 styleMask:(NSUInteger)aStyle
                   backing:(NSBackingStoreType)bufferingType
                     defer:(BOOL)flag
{
    self = [super initWithContentRect:contentRect
                            styleMask:aStyle
                              backing:bufferingType
                                defer:flag];
    if (self) {            
        [self setOpaque:NO];
        [self setBackgroundColor:[NSColor clearColor]];
        [self setMovableByWindowBackground:YES];
        [self setStyleMask:NSResizableWindowMask];
    }
    return self;
}
```

For further customisation refer [Apple sample code](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/RoundTransparentWindow/Introduction/Intro.html) http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/RoundTransparentWindow/Introduction/Intro.html

Answer (score 1):

Subclassing is the most flexible way.
If you don't want to subclass use this code.

```
// unfortunately the window can't be moved
// but this is just an alert type window, so i don't care
//
[window setOpaque:NO];
[window setBackgroundColor:[NSColor clearColor]];

NSView*  contentView = window.contentView;

contentView.wantsLayer = YES;
contentView.layer.backgroundColor = [NSColor windowBackgroundColor].CGColor;
contentView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 16.0;

[window makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
[window center];
```